# ui-router removes directory path from url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I've set up ui-router states like so:

```
    $stateProvider
        .state("login", {
            url: "/Login",
            templateUrl: "login.html",
            controller: "LoginController"
        })
        .state("createBooking",
        {
            url: "/CreateBooking",
            templateUrl: "createBooking.html",
            controller: "CreateBookingController"
        })
        .state("calendarView", {
            url: "/ViewBookings",
            templateUrl: "calendarView.html",
            controller: "CalendarController"
        });
```

which works fine when running on the localhost *(e.g. //localhost:[port]/Login)*

However, when I push to the dev server under a virtual directory 'SiteName' *(e.g. //dev.server.com/SiteName/Login)* then the virtual directory part of the path is stripped out *(e.g. //dev.server.com/Login)*

It also affects all of my services, as it's looking at *//server/serviceName* instead of *//server/directory/serviceName*

When I push the site to staging/production, I'll be using different paths again.

How can I set up ui-router to properly handle my various paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turned out that I needed to **remove** the html5mode.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

it now works with the urls showing as *//dev.server.com/SiteName/index#/Login*